# Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type)

Tags: django, tastypie

So I am trying to have my location filter url as `api/v1/labels/?brand_location=Australia` to filter brands with Australia only brands to return but keep receiving the error message:

```
{"error": "Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type)."}
```

But when use `api/v1/labels/?brand_location/=Australia` it works but doest filter Australia only locations, it returns the full response not excluding locations.

So my questions are:

1. How can I remove the trailing slash? And get it to filter Australia only locations
2. Is this the right way to go about this? When using foreign keys with django tastypie?

My code below:

**Models.py**

```
class Brand(models.Model):

    brand_location = models.ForeignKey('Location', null=True, blank=True, default="")


class Location(models.Model):

    state_or_country = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, blank=True, default="", verbose_name=_('Location'),
```

**api.py**

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        excludes = ['modified', 'id', 'created']

        queryset = Location.objects.all()

        resource_name = 'locations'

class LabelResource(ModelResource):

    brand_location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource, 'brand_location', full=True)

    class Meta:

        filtering = {
            "brand_location": ALL
        }

        queryset = Brand.objects.all()

        resource_name = 'labels'
```

**Snippet JSON Response**

```
{
  "labels": [
    {
      "brand_location": {
        "state_or_country": "Australia"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "limit": 6,
    "next": "/unlabel-network/unlabel-network-api/v1/labels/?limit=6&brand_location%2F=Australia&offset=6",
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 128
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`api/v1/labels/?brand_location=Australia` looks for `Location.id=Australia`.

Allow filtering deeper:

```
filtering = {
    "brand_location": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
}
```

and look for `state_or_country` field:

```
api/v1/labels/?brand_location__state_or_country=Australia
```

Comment: This is the new error I get when I use the above url you placed: {"error": "Lookups are not allowed more than one level deep on the 'brand_location' field."}

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add `filtering` to my `LocationResource` Then add `ALL_WITH_RELATIONS` to my filtering dict on my `LabelResource`

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        excludes = ['modified', 'id', 'created']

        queryset = Location.objects.all()

        resource_name = 'locations'

        filtering =  {
            "state_or_country": ALL
        }

class LabelResource(ModelResource):

    brand_location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource, 'brand_location', full=True)

    class Meta:

        filtering = {
            "brand_location": ALL,
            "brand_location": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

        queryset = Brand.objects.all()

        resource_name = 'labels'
```